# I am creating a program that will give a report on race times and I am trying to place them in first, second, third but when I compile I get zeros?

Tags: java, if-statement

```
public void sortTimesAscending() {
    //Finding which racer is first place
    if (timeOne > timeTwo && timeOne > timeThree) {
        timeOne = firstPlace;
    }else if (timeTwo > timeOne && timeTwo > timeThree) {
        timeTwo = firstPlace;
    }else if (timeThree > timeOne && timeThree > timeTwo) {
        timeThree = firstPlace;
    }

    //Finding which racer is third place
    if (timeOne < timeTwo && timeOne < timeThree) {
        timeOne = thirdPlace;
    }else if (timeTwo < timeOne && timeTwo < timeThree) {
        timeTwo = thirdPlace;
    }else if (timeThree < timeOne && timeThree < timeTwo) {
        timeThree = thirdPlace;
    }
    
    //Finding which racer is second place
    if (timeOne != firstPlace && timeOne != thirdPlace) {
        timeOne = secondPlace;
    }else if (timeTwo != firstPlace && timeTwo != thirdPlace) {
        timeTwo = secondPlace;
    }else if (timeThree != firstPlace && timeThree != thirdPlace) {
        timeThree = secondPlace;
    }

    System.out.println("First Place (time in seconds): " + firstPlace);
    System.out.println("Second Place (time in seconds): " + secondPlace);
    System.out.println("Third Place (time in seconds):" + thirdPlace);
}
```

The output I get is :
First Place (time in seconds): 0.0
Second Place (time in seconds): 0.0
Third Place (time in seconds):0.0

How can I fix this?

Comment: please post a [mcve]

Comment: Your assignments are the wrong way round. Change `timeOne = firstPlace;` to `firstPlace = timeOne;` This of course applies to all other assignments.

Comment: In most races, the faster time beats the slower time. If that's the case for your race, then first place would be the SMALLEST number of the three.  Your `if` statements for determining first place are using the wrong inequality check; change `>` to `<`, also taking into account Eritrean's comment and swapping the order of your assignments.

Comment: thank you for your help it is working smoothly now!